# Perlbrew fails to install perl-5.30.0, op/groups.t at fault?

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm attempting to install perl 5.30.0 from perl 5.16.3,  I run

`perlbrew install perl-5.30.0`

but the installation fails, even with `-f`,

and selections from the error file show:

```
~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0$ grep -A1 -B1 -i failed /home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.30.0.log
    opmini.o perlmini.o  gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro_core.o keywords.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o caretx.o dquote.o time64.o  miniperlmain.o  -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc 
./miniperl -w -Ilib -Idist/Exporter/lib -MExporter -e '<?>' || sh -c 'echo >&2 Failed to build miniperl.  Please run make minitest; exit 1'
./miniperl -Ilib -f write_buildcustomize.pl
--
op/grep.t .......................................................... ok
# Failed test 1 - perl's `$(' agrees with `id -a 2>/dev/null || id 2>/dev/null' at op/groups.t line 117
op/groups.t ........................................................ 
Failed 1/2 subtests 
op/gv.t ............................................................ ok
--
-------------------
op/groups.t                                                      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
Files=2656, Tests=1219021, 1082 wallclock secs (100.74 usr 14.39 sys + 712.86 cusr 87.83 csys = 915.82 CPU)
--
make: *** [test_harness] Error 1
##### Brew Failed #####
```

I can't find a solution on Google searches, I've found something similar on https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=116775 but I don't see the solution, and I'm not even sure if that person had the same problem.

How can I get perl-5.30.0 installed on my perlbrew?

```
~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0$ id -a
uid=1227493(703404669) gid=60513(domain users) groups=60513(domain users),10(wheel),2000(bioinfom),2002(docker),3001(BUILTIN\users),3002(geno studies),3003(clm_users),3004(shrsf_all_employees),3005(svh_owa_ext),3006(svh_owa_non),3007(citrix access gateway),3008(citrix - ms outlook 2010),94696(citrix access gateway),94773(clm_users),95046(geno studies),97178(svh_owa_ext),97179(svh_owa_non),137580(shrsf_all_employees),529018(citrix - ms outlook 2010),562127(sp lab clsi link visitors),564451(fgo_owa_non),576177(shrsf_esbc_biobank),576507(sioux falls region users),615672(fargo remote e-mail),637092(sf remote access audit group),639414(fgo remote access audit group),642499(all emps_all regions),656741(all sites_sioux falls_sd),657700(all emps_system_all regions),657701(all emps_system_sf region),659636(all emps_sf region),667588,669081(polycom-cantonhosp-cart1-author),677540(room-sf-surgicaltower dakotafoodcourttiledarea-author),677669(rtls_standard),677823(room-sf-surgicaltower g734residencyclassroom-reviewer),703542(benefits_all_sf region),703546(benefits_emps_sf region),709223(benefits_all_all regions),709224(benefits_emps_all regions),716197(remote access audit cag),716198(remote access audit owa),716199(remote access audit vpn),719364(room-sf-stevenscenter publicaffairs),719474(equipment-sf-sanfordcenter-intlclinicsconfline-reviewers),722319(all emps_all regions_&_affiliates),725674(ent mobile connect),736131(ent lync users),760563(policies_sioux falls),796245(all emps_all regions_nonnested),797952(imagenetics - sioux falls),889435(one chart remote ent),889439(workflow tracer ent),1021861(avaya one-x communicator - sf),1037894(onerpt-admin-general),1112173(ent asa allowed),1127635(hrcommunications),1137950(ent remote connect),1137980(sioux falls users),1173104(all emps_all regions_non union),1192175(fgo owa groups),1206723(all emps_all regions_annual increase),1225668(ent symantec encryption users),1227493(703404669),1232214(avaya one-x communicator - sf-sp12),1236548(sccm_app_user_workflow tracer - mtn time - ltsr),1238714(sccm_app_user_workflow tracer - ltsr),1240689(sccm_app_user_one chart remote - ltsr),1242875 context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0$ ./perl -le'print $('
60513 10 2000 2002 3001 3002 3003 3004 3005 3006 3007 3008 60513 94696 94773 95046 97178 97179 137580 529018 562127 564451 576177 576507 615672 637092 639414 642499 656741 657700 657701 659636 667588 669081 677540 677669 677823 703542 703546 709223 709224 716197 716198 716199 719364 719474 722319 725674 736131 760563 796245 797952 889435 889439 1021861 1037894 1112173 1127635 1137950 1137980 1173104 1192175 1206723 1225668 1227493 1232214 1236548 1238714 1240689 1242875
```

Comment: [`groups.t` of 5.30.3](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/44523d1ffde5f23de2e13216cdbac46357631904:/t/op/groups.t)

Comment: OS? Output of `id -a`?

Comment: It's probably a bad test rather than an actual problem.

Comment: @ikegami this is a CentOS system, id -a gives an answer too long to post here.  `rpm -q centos-release` gives `centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64`

Comment: To long to add to your question?

Comment: @ikegami  I have added the output of `id -a` to the question

Comment: And the output of `./perl -le'print $('` run from the build directory. (I think it's the `build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0` subdir of your perlbrew dir)

Comment: @ikegami `703404669@bioitutil2:~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0$ ./perl -le'print $('
60513 10 2000 2002 3001 3002 3003 3004 3005 3006 3007 3008 60513 94696 94773 95046 97178 97179 137580 529018 562127 564451 576177 576507 615672 637092 639414 642499 656741 657700 657701 659636 667588 669081 677540 677669 677823 703542 703546 709223 709224 716197 716198 716199 719364 719474 722319 725674 736131 760563 796245 797952 889435 889439 1021861 1037894 1112173 1127635 1137950 1137980 1173104 1192175 1206723 1225668 1227493 1232214 1236548 1238714 1240689 1242875`

Comment: I tried to step through, but it turned out to be more work than anticipated to fudge the code to allow me to do that on my system. Instead, let's start by running `t/TEST op/groups.t` from `~/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0`

Comment: @ikegami `t/op/groups ... skipped
FAILED--no tests were run for some reason.` "for some reason" isn't very helpful

Comment: huh? It wasn't skipped earlier. ?!?!

Comment: Well, in any case, that's the command you need to debug.

Comment: @ikegami I really don't know how to debug this, when I run `perl groups.t` it says that it can't find test.pl in @INC how can I get this test.pl?

Comment: `perl groups.t` is not the proper way to run `groups.t`, `t/TEST op/groups.t` (from the build dir) is

Comment: @ikegami would it be okay to run "--notest"? I have no idea how to proceed with this

Comment: Yeah, you could ignore the error. At worse, some of user-group related stuff might not work. At best, it's a bad test and everything will work correctly.